# Dividable numbers in c#(probably easy answer)

Tags: c#

I have an assignment to write a c# programme that first off reads 3 numbers.

CASE1:
IF none of these numbers are dividable with 3 OR 1 of the numbers is dividable with 3, the values stay the same.
For instance:
User enters: 7 -5 6
Program outputs: 7 -5 6

CASE2:
ELSE IF ONLY TWO numbers are dividable with 3, the programme takes the one with the higher value and increases that value for 1.
For instance:
User enters: 9 -5 6
Program outputs: 10 -5 6 //SO IT TOOK THE HIGHER ONE(9) AND added +1 so it became (10)

CASE3:
BUT if these two numbers are the same, then the program adds +1 to the number that was written in second
For instance:
user enters:9 4 9
Program outputs: 9 4 10 (program adds +1 to the last 9 because it was written out second)

CASE4:
BUT if ALL the 3 numbers are dividable with 3, then the program adds the second number +1 and the last number +2
For instance:
User enters: 9 -6 6
Program outputs: 9 -5 8

SOLUTION TO CASE: 1 //NOT FOUND
So I have this so far, and if I enter: " 4 4 4" the program returns "4 4 4" to me. But if I enter "3 4 4" or "4 3 4" or "4 4 3" the program returns "dog", but it should still return the 3 numbers to me, because only 1 is dividable with 3.

```
  {

            int a, b, c;
            Console.WriteLine("Vnesite prvo stevilo: ");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Vnesite drugo stevilo: ");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Vnesite tretje stevilo: ");
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           if((a%3!=0) && (b%3!=0) && (c%3!=0) || (a%3!=0) && (b%3==0) && (c%3==0) || (a%3==0) && (b%3!=0) && (c%3==0) || (a%3==0) && (b%3==0) && (c%3!=0))
           {
               Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c);
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("dog");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }

        }
```

SOLUTION TO CASE 2: NOT FOUND
SOLUTION TO CASE 3: NOT FOUND
SOLUTION TO CASE 4: NOT FOUND

Comment: You shouldnt put all conditions in one if statement. Simply use `else if` and put second condition in it and do your logic inside it. Then another `else if` would be third condition etc...

Comment: I cannot find a question in here. What's your specific question?

Comment: @EricLippert: My impression is the OP wants help finding the other cases. I think if OP follows kazem's suggestion, he/she will be on the right track and will probably solve it himself/herself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to make a few suggestions.

For the first case, just check whether two are not divisible by three. In any case, if two are not divisible, it will satisfy the criteria:

```
// Divisible by three booleans:
bool a3 = (a % 3 == 0);
bool b3 = (b % 3 == 0);
bool c3 = (c % 3 == 0);

// Case 1:
if ((!a3 && !b3) || (!b3 && !c3) || (!a3 && !c3))
```

Then for your second and third case, just make sure not every number is indivisible by three:

```
// Case 2 & 3:
else if (!(!a3 && !b3 && !c3))
```

Then you know only two are divisible by three. Go through each possibility of two numbers, like:

```
if (a3 && b3)
{
    if (a > b)
        a++;
    else
        b++;
}
```

As long as it's in that order, it will satisfy Case 3 as well. Then handle your last case. I'm sure this will put you on the right track.

I have tried to only show you what will help you figure it out yourself. You may run into some problems depending on how you are approaching this. You are on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this solved all 4 cases for me. But what I don't understand is how to read out

!(a%3!=0 && b%3!=0 && c%3!=0)
can you explain this? it works but I don't know how

Comment: Sure! Replace each Exclamation point with NOT: (NOT(NOTa3 && NOTb3 && NOTc3)). a3 means that the integer a is divisible by 3, so !a3 means that a is not divisible by three. Since we already checked whether 2 of 3 numbers were not divisible by three, we know that at least two of the three numbers are divisible. We are just making sure that not ALL 3 of the numbers are not divisible by three (because that is reserved for the last case).

Answer (score 0):

The code below is how I would go about solving this one.

Here is my Logic:

You have three things you need to keep track of.

1) How many are divisible by three

2) do any of them equal each other

3) what is the largest number

After you solve for those components it is just a matter of nesting them correctly.

Let it be known I purposefully put a bug in here that will trigger some of the time. Good rule of thumb is to never rip code and just expect it to work before looking it over.

```
try
{
int a, b, c;
int count = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Vnesite prvo stevilo: ");
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool a1 = (a % 3 == 0);
if (a1) count++;

Console.WriteLine("Vnesite drugo stevilo: ");
b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool b1 = (b % 3 == 0);
if (b1) count++;

Console.WriteLine("Vnesite tretje stevilo: ");
c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool c1 = (c % 3 == 0);
if (c1) count++;

if (count == 3)
{
    b++;
    c += 2;
}

if (count == 2)
{
    if (a1 & b1 & a != b) b++;
    else if ((a1 & c1 && a == c) || (b1 & c1 & b == c)) c++;
    else
    {
        int[] abc = { a, b, c };
        if (a == abc.Max()) a++;
        else if (b == abc.Max()) b++;
        else if (c == abc.Max()) c++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", a, b, c));
Console.ReadKey();
}

catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("dog");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```